# No return in Delete Node Function Linked List - Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am learning linked list from scratch in Python and am trying to implement a music player using the same. However, I was trying to create a function `delete_song()` to delete songs with reference from some coding sites and in most of them I saw the following piece of code:

```
def delete_song(self, song_name):

        temp = self.head_node

        if (temp is not None):
            if (temp.data == song_name):
                self.head_node = temp.next
                temp = None
                return

        while(temp is not None):
            if(temp.data == song_name):
                break
            prev = temp
            temp = temp.next

        if(temp == None):
            return

        prev.next = temp.next

        temp = None
```

My questions are:

> i) The data of Head Node is being stored in `temp` variable, and the `if (temp is not None)` part is clear. But, how does the `while (temp is not None)` loop traverse through the entire linked list (in case head does not match with key value) and search for the key value?

> ii) Why is there no return at the end of the `delete_song` function?

My questions might be silly but I am unable to get an explanation to this logic. Any help is appreciated! TIA

Comment: i) `temp = temp.next` ii) The function does not return a value so a `return` statement is not required. You can add `return` if you want, but it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Explained in comments so do check.

```py
while(temp is not None):
            if(temp.data == song_name): # if match is found then break the loop
                break
            prev = temp # store current node as previous node
            temp = temp.next # get the reference/value of next node in temp
            """
            And at last node `temp.next` will be `None` which will be 
            stored in `temp` which will make `while` condition `False` 
            and it will come out.
            """

if(temp == None): # if traversal is over then temp will be None 
            return # and it will return or complete the execution

# In case it found the song in while loop then after break
# below code will be responsible for deleting that node as follows
prev.next = temp.next # store the next node value/reference in prev node

temp = None # delete the current node
```

As for there's no return at the end of the `delete_song()` is because it does not want to return any value or notify it because it will be over whether if song is deleted or whether song is not found to be deleted.

For any clarification please comment